# make R shiny renderPlot reactive to text input

Tags: r, bioinformatics, shiny

I am working on my first Shiny app and am having trouble making an input argument for my plot reactive to a user's input into a textInput box.

Here is a slimmed down example of the code this should look familiar to those of you who have worked with shiny before.

```
#ui.R
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Shiny App"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(h2("Menu"),

mainPanel(h1("Main"),
tabPanel("Differential Expression",
         column(6,
               p("Input your gene of interest below"),
               textInput(uiOutput("GeneVariable"), label = h4("Gene of interest"),
               value = "Gjb2"),
               submitButton("Submit")),
         plotOutput("plot2"),

    )
  )
))
```

.

```
#server.R
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

 output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    scde.test.gene.expression.difference("GeneVariable", 
                                         models=o.ifm, counts=cd, prior=o.prior)
  })

GeneVariable <- reactive({ ###I don't know what to put here#####
  })
})
```

I need the user to be able to input a gene name into the textInput box in the "GeneVariable" position and have name processed by the scde.test.gene.expression.difference function.

Thanks for your help and patience i am new to this.

Comment: is there some code missing?

Comment: Yes, I tried to copy out only the relevant parts of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following worked to solve this problem

```
#ui.R
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Shiny App"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(h2("Menu"),

mainPanel(h1("Main"),
tabPanel("Differential Expression",
         column(6,
               p("Input your gene of interest below"),
               textInput("input$GeneVariable"), label = h4("Gene of interest"),
               value = "Gjb2"),
               submitButton("Submit")),
         plotOutput("plot2"),

    )
  )
))
```

.

```
#server.R
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

 output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    scde.test.gene.expression.difference(input$`input$GeneVariable`, 
                                         models=o.ifm, counts=cd, prior=o.prior)
  })

GeneVariable <- reactive({input$GeneVariable})
  })
})
```

The key was using the `input$'input$GeneVariable'` to essentially print the reactive input of the user into the plot function.